# Where can i find n2n consensus algorithm informations?

Tags: blockchain, corda, consensus

I wanna develop n2n protocol on my blockchain platform.
I heard n2n is a very secure protocol that is developed on corda blockchain platform by r3cev corp.
But I cannot fine any document or codes for n2n protocol.
Could you tell me where can i find document and codes?

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Corda does not use an "N2N" consensus protocol. It uses standard RAFT or Byzantine Fault Tolerant consensus algorithms.

Developers also have the option of implementing their own notary consensus algorithms.